# what exactly is the DOM? and what is an object as taken from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

I know a bit of Javascript and have recently started trying to tie it into HTML with the code academy course. in the following code:

```
function sayHello(name){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Hello ' + name + '!';
}
```

The "document" in the above code is the DOM?

That would mean that getElements is a property (function) of document, and that innerHTML is a function of the getElements function.... right?

If I am seeing this correctly, how is it possible that DOM objects have javascript properties/functions?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Is `document` the DOM

**Short answer**

Yes, in the sense that it is the root of it.

**Slightly longer answer**

The [Document Object Model (DOM)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html) is what the browser exposes to the JavaScript runtime to allow JavaScript code to manipulate the page (its nodes and associated metadata). `document` is one part of the DOM.

#### How can the DOM have JavaScript properties

**Short answer**

They don't.

**Slightly longer answer**

The DOM is not actually managed in JavaScript (yet).  It is typically managed by a separate engine altogether, written in a lower-level language like C++ or Rust (in the case of Mozilla's Servo project).  The JavaScript runtime is *also* written in a lower-level language (again, C++ is most likely) and certain attributes of the DOM are *exposed* to the JavaScript runtime *as if they were native JavaScript objects*.  The fact that they are not makes all kinds of interesting things possible ... and generally make it so that these DOM objects [do not always behave as you would expect "real" JavaScript objects to behave](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) (for example `typeof querySelectorAll` in IE 8 returns "object", not "function" as one would reasonably expect).

Comment: Good answer. I'd award bonus points for actually referring to the W3C Recommendation which defines the DOM.

Comment: @keshlam - it's already there as a link to the latest Candidate Recommendation for HTML5 :-)  And thanks!

Comment: Rephrasing for clarity: I wish I could given you  bonus points, which you deserve since you actually referred to the W3C Recommendation which defines the DOM. (And now I sorta can, by upvoting your response to my unclear comment.)

Answer (score 3):

the Document Object Model is a model for interacting with HTML. They do not have "javascript properties" or "functions", javascript functions are executed on HTML elements which are found through the DOM.

```
getElementbyID
```

is a function in javascript, which retrieves a HTML element based on the DOM. Below is what the DOM looks like, and is how javascript will execute the aforementioned function.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

[image]

Comment: Be careful citing w3schools.com. They may have improved, but I've spent just a bit too much time in the past re-educating folks their articles have misled.

Answer (score 2):

Close. `document` is the root element in the DOM, or Document Object Model. The DOM is the in-memory representation of the current document.

Calling `document.getElementById()` returns an HTML element, which has the property `innerHTML`. Writing to `innerHTML` tells the browser to render the string as that element's children.

DOM objects do not have javascript-dependent properties or attributes. Javascript is just one way of accessing DOM attributes.

Answer (score 2):

DOM can be thought as an **Interface** (provide by layout engine like **Gecko** in Google Chrome and Firefox ) between the **HTML** and **Any_Other_language**
 **{like JavaScript}** that want to use the html. 
Say Tomorrow If a new language is born ( something similar to javaScript but a new language that has it's engine implemented in the browser like JavaScript has **V8 engine** in Google Chrome ) that want to play around with HTML, then just to access the HTML they don't have to write some hefty low level code( inside the engine for this language ) instead they can use **DOM_Interface** ( inside the browser ) to access and this makes it easy for them to concentrate on their logic.

Comment: Though this would require a browser to implement that new language? Otherwise how would you access the DOM_interface?

Comment: @ZachSmith Right browser needs to incorporate an engine for the new language and that engine need to use to DOM_Interface in place writing  low level code  for the same.

Comment: Is it possible to access a browser's DOM interface externally?

Comment: There were Scripting language like VB Script supported in IE till IE 10. It also used DOM for using HTML element for various purpose. Thing to note is DOM_Interface is provided by browser so it totally depends on browser vendor whether DOM_Interface is available to outside world for use. As of now I guess no one is supporting that but if you want you can write an extension for Firefox to access DOM outside,  for a web page that is opened inside Firefox.

Comment: @ZachSmith No, the DOM does not necessarily need to be part of a browser at all. There are [quite a few standalone implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model#Libraries) in various languages.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. What would be a use case for a standalone DOM implementation? I think I have used one of these for testing purposes (phantom.js). But my understanding is that the DOM is strictly HTML for representation?

Comment: @ZachSmith The DOM is for every kind of XML document, and gets used for manipulating them with or without visual representation.

Answer (score 1):

DOM is Document Object Model ie your whole document is the hierarchy of objects with Window being the parent of all.

It provides a structured representation of the document (a tree) and it defines a way that the structure can be accessed from programs so that they can change the document structure, style and content.